# angular ng-repeat with condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Products have 4 different category. I want to show them into 3 section. How to do this with angularjs? I want to repeat ng-repeat  based on product category.

Please check my plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/XdB2tv03RvYLrUsXFRbw?p=preview

```
var product = [

  {
    "name": "Item 1",
    "dimension": {
      "height": "4 in",
      "width": "3 in"
    },
    "category": "A"
  }, {
    "name": "Item 2",
    "dimension": {
      "height": "2 in",
      "width": "6 in"
    },
    "category": "B"
  }, {
    "name": "Item 3",
    "dimension": {
      "height": "2 in",
      "width": "3 in"
    },
    "category": "C"
  }, {
    "name": "Item 4",
    "dimension": {
      "height": "5 in",
      "width": "2 in"
    },
    "category": "D"
  }

];
```

Comment: wow ... 3 identical answers none of which address the condition for combining categories

Answer (score 8):

You can use a filter :

```
ng-repeat="item in output.products | filter:{ category: 'A'}"
```

**Edit** : looks like everybody googled the same thig and found the same other StackOverflow answer ^^ @OP you should learn how to Google, btw !

**Edit 2** : Reread the question, you need a custom filter :

```
app.filter('category', function() {
  return function(items, categories) {
    if (!items || items.length === 0) {
      return [];
    }

    return items.filter(function(item) {
      return categories.indexOf(item.category) > -1;
    });
  };
});
```

Use it like follows :

```
ng-repeat="item in output.products | category:['A', 'B']"
```

**Edit 3** : be aware, though, that this can be pretty expensive in terms of performances for huge arrays. If you're dealing with such arrays, I suggest pre-filtering the data into several subarrays.

Comment: where's the `or` condition?

Comment: What do you mean ? In the example I gave, if an item's category is in the list given to the filter, it will match.

Comment: right, but that was after the complete rewrite of the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module.

You will have to define your own map function in the controller:

```
$scope.group = function(elem){
    if(elem.category == 'C' || elem.category=='D'){
       elem.category = 'C OR D' ;
       return elem;
    }
    else return elem;
}
```

then in the html

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in products | map: group | groupBy: 'category'">
  Group name: {{ key }}
  <li ng-repeat="product in value">
     player: {{ product.name }} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

note that you are loosing the information on the category of the element if it is C Or D, thing that won't happen if you use LoremIpsum's answer, but with this solution you will be able to create whatever groups you want. 
here is a [js fiddle](http://jsbin.com/rowotosiwe/edit?html,js,output) with an example.

Answer (score 1):

for example `<div class="" ng-repeat="item in output.products | filter: {category:'A'}">` Whould only repeat items with Category A. You could also filter with a self defined function or other criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng.if for this to.

Check here http://plnkr.co/edit/SKfUKTtKhUnZqec3ABSt?p=preview

```
  <div class="" ng-repeat="item in output.products" ng-if='item.category =="A"'>
```